# Google calendar app without Google Play Services

Tags: android, calendar, google-play-services

I want to install Google Calendar app on an android device that does not run Google Play Services, and it should stay that way. any suggestions? I've read about CALDAV and microG, but couldn't manage with either of them. if u can reply with a detailed explanation, I would really appreciate that. my final goal is to be able to sync with various calendars on android without google play services. (gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc....)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

GMS app depends on google framework.Play store is essential for GMS.
You can hide the launch icon in Launcher if you don't wanna see it.

Answer (score 0):

ICSx5 is an awesome app that sync calendars. And it's compatible with Google. Additionally, it's sister CalDavx5 is a good choice.